# How to use OpenGL context in SDL2?

Tags: opengl, sdl, sdl-2, opengl-3

My questions are

1. How to use OpenGL context in SDL2?
2. What library/libraries is/are needed to use OpenGL in SDL2?

I am on Windows 10, vs2019.

I am trying use OpenGL context in SDL2.
I followed the tutorial in the below link.
In the tutorial, their link to gl3.h is dead, 404.

https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tutorial1:_Creating_a_Cross_Platform_OpenGL_3.2_Context_in_SDL_(C_/_SDL)

I tried to get a copy from their GitHub, and I don't think that the correct one.

https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenGL-Registry

I also tried glew, (glad, Core 3.0, no extension). glew doesn't work.

glad kind of work, but I get an error

```
Exception thrown at 0x0000000000000000 in GLTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x0000000000000000.
```

The error above is referring to the line

```
    glClear ( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT ); <<< this line
```

full code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/* If using gl3.h */
/* Ensure we are using opengl's core profile only */
#define GL3_PROTOTYPES 1
//#include <GL3/gl3.h>

#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#define PROGRAM_NAME "Tutorial1"

/* A simple function that prints a message, the error code returned by SDL,
 * and quits the application */
void sdldie(const char *msg)
{
    printf("%s: %s\n", msg, SDL_GetError());
    SDL_Quit();
    exit(1);
}


void checkSDLError(int line = -1)
{
#ifndef NDEBUG
    const char *error = SDL_GetError();
    if (*error != '\0')
    {
        printf("SDL Error: %s\n", error);
        if (line != -1)
            printf(" + line: %i\n", line);
        SDL_ClearError();
    }
#endif
}
 

/* Our program's entry point */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Window *mainwindow; /* Our window handle */
    SDL_GLContext maincontext; /* Our opengl context handle */

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) /* Initialize SDL's Video subsystem */
        sdldie("Unable to initialize SDL"); /* Or die on error */

    /* Request opengl 3.2 context.
     * SDL doesn't have the ability to choose which profile at this time of writing,
     * but it should default to the core profile */
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);

    /* Turn on double buffering with a 24bit Z buffer.
     * You may need to change this to 16 or 32 for your system */
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);

    /* Create our window centered at 512x512 resolution */
    mainwindow = SDL_CreateWindow(PROGRAM_NAME, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        512, 512, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (!mainwindow) /* Die if creation failed */
        sdldie("Unable to create window");

    checkSDLError(__LINE__);

    /* Create our opengl context and attach it to our window */
    maincontext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(mainwindow);
    checkSDLError(__LINE__);


    /* This makes our buffer swap syncronized with the monitor's vertical refresh */
    SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);

    /* Clear our buffer with a red background */
    glClearColor ( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
    glClear ( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Right Here
    /* Swap our back buffer to the front */
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(mainwindow);
    /* Wait 2 seconds */
    SDL_Delay(2000);

    /* Same as above, but green */
    glClearColor ( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
    glClear ( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(mainwindow);
    SDL_Delay(2000);

    /* Same as above, but blue */
    glClearColor ( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
    glClear ( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(mainwindow);
    SDL_Delay(2000);

    /* Delete our opengl context, destroy our window, and shutdown SDL */
    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(maincontext);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(mainwindow);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Downloading `gl3.h` manually isn't going to work. You should use Glew or Glad. Pick any of the two, and show us what errors you get when you try it.

Comment: Is that your *complete* [mcve]?  Because I'm not seeing you initialize GLAD anywhere.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I did try glew and glad. The error above is from glad. With glew, the example I copied from the tutorial site did not compile.

Comment: @genpfault The code I show here was from the tutorial from khronos wiki. I didn't write a single line of code. I did not initialize glad. I assume the example code should work.

Comment: All I tried is to put the correct library. I comment out //#include <GL3/gl3.h>, put #include <glad/glad.h>

Comment: Well, you need to initialize GLAD after you do `SDL_GL_CreateContext`. If you used GLEW, it would also needed to be initialized.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I did a quick google,<https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library#glad_.28Multi-Language_GL.2FGLES.2FEGL.2FGLX.2FWGL_Loader-Generator.29>

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, thank you. It works with glad only, I only need gladLoadGL.